# How can I enumerate the loaded add-ins in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, vbe

If I have a database open, and I've used the Zoom functionality (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) in a table field, then Access has opened the `Utility.accda` add-in (as evidenced by the appearance of Utility in the VBE). Some other actions will also open `ACWZTOOL.ACCDE`. So, my VBE shows 3 projects...

How can I enumerate the paths of each add-in/database?

I'm trying to execute some SQL against the `MSysObjects` table in each database, but I don't think I can do that using the Access object model without opening a connection to each add-in path.

Comment: Not that it's a guarantee, but could you look in: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, I forgot that I could access the filename from each VBProject...

This enumerates all of the paths of any open database and add-in.

```
Sub EnumPaths()

  Dim proj
  For Each proj In VBE.VBProjects
    Debug.Print proj.FileName
  Next proj

End Sub
```

Comment: Re "...enumerate the paths of each add-in/database..." my Assess DB has two add-ins, but your code here lists only the path to my Access DB and nothing for either Add-In.

Comment: Are they VBA add-ins or COM add-ins? Are they visible in VBE?

Comment: They are MDA's, which are not visible in VBE, nor are they COMAddIn's. I have Avery, which is a COMAddIn, plus two mda's. The code I listed earlier shows the COMAddIn's, but I have been unable to 'list' the MDA's.  I can search the Registry and get a list from: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Menu Add-Ins\

Comment: Hmm, I thought the MDAs were loaded on-demand. The utility ACCDA only appears in the VBE *after* I've used Zoom (or some other utility feature). I wonder if your MDAs are present but not yet used/loaded?

Comment: Yes, if I invoke the add-in, then can see in VBE. Therefore your code above will show the path.